# Avoid getting previous errors in rxjs Subject (asObservable) on new subscriptions

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a service (singleton) in angular that exposes an rxjs Subject as an observable. A component subscribes to the observable. When an error occurs in the observable, the component gets the error and displays it. However, if the user navigates away from the component, then navigates back, immediately the error is thrown again.

see 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nboawu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually the behavior of Subjects (and also Observables) in general. If there is an error happening this stream ends. Therefore it is pretty uncommon to emit an error in a Subject especially when you use it for statemanagement in angular applications. 
The error channel is also rather used for technical errors that happens inside your observable, for "error scenarios" I'd rather use the next channel but emit a complex object there, maybe something like

```
export interface SearchQueryResult {
  data: SOMETHING,
  error: any
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Subject.error`, the Subject gets stopped and nothing happens to it afterwards, so you shouldn't use that.

That will fix your issue, besides as a suggestion catch the api errors yourself and process them as you wish. For example, you might store them somewhere or you might use [Sentry.io](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/angular/) (Sentry has free tier and works well with Angular).

For example:

```
this.api.getData().pipe(
  catchError(error => this.doSomethingWithError(error)),
);
```